# How to select buttons in a dialog using the keyboard?

Tags: mac, keyboard, preferences

Times ago I setted my Mac (in system preferences) to use, when an alert appear, enter key to choose OK button and tab to scroll other possible button and space to select one of them.
Now I initialized my Mac and I can't find the preference again, does somebody know where is it? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably searching for the option "Full Keyboard Access".

You can find it under System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts

[image]

Comment: Yes thank you so much!!! I searched there for 10 minutes without looking at bottom part of window!! -_-

Comment: Please do not use the comment section to say "Thank you" altough you are welcome. Please see [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more information